# Replication using Datagaurd to FAR DR

Tags: oracle, replication, dataguard

We have already setup Oracle replication using Dataguard from a primary active site to a near DR site. The near DR is a passive site.

Is it possible to replicate from the Near DR (Passive) site to Far DR site using dataguard?

Comment: if you'd like to get most benefit then FAR sync should be close to primary and should connect to primary. I have not implemented this (there is no need for me) but this is my understanding. Your primary could write to FAR Sync as well as your current DR. It would be a possible issue if you have maximum protection mode but it should be ok for max performance mode. You must test though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

[Cascaded Redo Transport Destinations](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/log_transport.htm#SBYDB5122)

> A cascaded redo transport destination (also known as a terminal
>   destination) receives primary database redo indirectly from a standby
>   database rather than directly from a primary database.
>
> A physical standby database that cascades primary database redo to one
>   or more terminal destinations at the same time it is applying changes
>   to its local database files is known as a cascading standby database.

More details at the above URL.